# Write data into table for each of the 31 days using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Basically I am using PowerShell to fetch data from backup software and then write it into a table. I have no problem with this part, as I am fetching one day worth of data and then writing it into a table where the rows are the server names and the column shows "Success" or "Failure".

I want to be able to make one table, where the rows show the server names and the columns show day 1 to 31, and then "Success" or "Failure" for each day. I hope this makes sense.

```powershell
$format = "<style>"
$format = $format + "{font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt;}"
$format = $format + "TABLE{border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;}"
$format = $format + "TH{border: 1px solid black; background: #dddddd; padding: 5px; }"
$format = $format + "TD{border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px; }"
$format = $format + "</style>"

$sessions = Get-VBRBackupSession | Where-Object {$_.JobType -eq "Backup" -and $_.EndTime -ge (Get-Date).addhours(-24)}
$realsessions = $sessions.gettasksessions()

$table = @()

foreach ($session in $realsessions) {


$backupobject = New-Object PSObject
$backupobject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Job Name" -Value $session.JobName
$backupobject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Server Name" -Value $session.Name
$backupobject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Backup Status" -Value $session.Status

$table += $backupobject

}
$table | ConvertTo-Html -Head $format -body "<H2>Veeam Backup Report</H2>" | Out-File "C:\Temp\VeeamBackupReport.xls"
```

Output of $sessions:

```
BottleneckManager         : CJobBottleneckManager
Info                      : Veeam.Backup.Model.CBackupSessionInfo
Progress                  : Veeam.Backup.Model.CBackupProgressData
StartupMode               : Normal
JobSourceType             : VDDK
CurrentPointId            : 0b833e92-0f45-4b75-bb40-f8c80a696df9
OriginalSessionId         : 5bfdc2bf-d17b-40aa-9e5f-d5e44b19ca67
IsFullMode                : False
IsRetryMode               : False
IsVeeamZip                : False
PostActivity              : AskService
Name                      : Daily_Backups
OrigJobName               : Daily_Backups
BackupStats               : Veeam.Backup.Model.CBackupStats
WorkDetails               : Veeam.Backup.Core.CBackupSessionWorkDetails
WillBeRetried             : False
IsManuallyStopped         : False
StorageVerificationResult : Veeam.Backup.Core.CStorageVerificationResultContainer
SessionInfo               : Veeam.Backup.Model.CBackupSessionInfo
Id                        : 5bfdc2bf-d17b-40aa-9e5f-d5e44b19ca67
JobType                   : Backup
JobName                   : Daily_Backups
JobSpec                   :
JobTypeString             : Other job type
Operation                 :
Description               :
BaseProgress              : 100
IsCompleted               : True
IsWorking                 : False
JobId                     : 843d4014-5dda-4dfb-8590-949d7ed843ce
Result                    : Success
State                     : Stopped
EndTime                   : 2015/04/11 04:12:36 AM
CreationTime              : 2015/04/10 10:00:20 PM
AuxData                   : <AuxData><CBackupStats><BackupSize>46279333376</BackupSize><DataSize>97487622667</DataSize>
                            <DedupRatio>99</DedupRatio><CompressRatio>47</CompressRatio></CBackupStats><CBackupSessionW
                            orkDetails><WorkDuration>223365199270</WorkDuration></CBackupSessionWorkDetails></AuxData>
IsLowerAgentPriority      : True
LogName                   : Job.Daily_Backups
LogsSubFolder             : Daily_Backups
Logger                    : Veeam.Backup.Core.XmlLogger
Tracer                    : Veeam.Backup.Core.CSessionLogTracer
```

Output of $RealSessions

```
JobSess         : Veeam.Backup.Core.CBackupSession
Info            : Veeam.Backup.Model.CBackupTaskSessionInfo
ProgressManager : Veeam.Backup.Core.CBackupTaskSessionProgress
WorkTimer       : Veeam.Backup.Core.CBackupTaskSessionWorkTimer
Id              : 3767cd65-8de9-423e-b77e-6850ebb95dab
Name            : Server1
Status          : Success
Operation       :
Progress        : Veeam.Backup.Model.CBackupProgressData
CurrentDiskNum  : 1
Logger          : Veeam.Backup.Core.XmlLogger
Tracer          : Veeam.Backup.Core.CSessionLogTracer
WillBeRetried   : False
RetryCounter    : 0
JobSessId       : 5bfdc2bf-d17b-40aa-9e5f-d5e44b19ca67
JobName         : Daily_Backups
```

Comment: What if you check what day it was? If its the first of the month it will overwrite the file contents. Any other day would append. Could even make the file named after the date as to not ruin previous data.

Comment: Yeah apologies I want it to append. So for instance I want a column for day 1,2,3...31 and each day must be appended. Would you be able to point on the right path as to how to do this?

Comment: Does this _really_ need to be in HTML. It is not a simple matter of just appending the data since HTML is a more complex structure. If you just had csv File output then appending would be a breeze. Would be nice to know your thoughts. Else we need to parse the current file and add the new data to then re-output. Depending on how much data you have that could be a costly venture (of time).

Comment: Hi Matt. No it definitely does not need to be in HTML, I really just used that for testing as it displays nicely in excel and can be copied. I would love to hear your suggestions for how I can append if using a CSV :) Thank you for taking the time.

Comment: Sorry Scryptor while I know I could figure this out I cant do it without the environment. You need to use `Group-Object` for the name and then use an index to step through the times.

Comment: Understood Matt. Dont know if the additional info I posted in the main question will help at all? If not, would you mind giving me an example of an index please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to add another answer. While my other answer is incorrect for your case I would like to leave it in case it adds value for someone else.

What we need to do is get all the `$realsessions` out while keeping their `endtime` that comes from the original output of `Get-VBRBackupSession`

```-powershell
$days = 31
$sessions = Get-VBRBackupSession | Where-Object {$_.JobType -eq "Backup" -and $_.EndTime -ge (Get-Date).AddDays(-$days)}
$realsessions = $sessions | ForEach-Object{
    # Get session information
    $endtime = [datetime]$_.EndTime

    # Create a custom object for each real session that keeps some session info.
    $_.gettasksessions() | ForEach-Object{
        New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property @{
            ServerName = $_.Name
            JobName = $_.JobName
            BackupStatus = $_.Status
            EndTime = $endtime
        }
    } 
}

# You should check the content of $realsessions to be sure it is organized right
$realsessions | Group-Object ServerName | ForEach-Object{
    # Collect the server group
    $serverGroup = $_.Group

    # Start building the object using the first element
    $props = @{
        ServerName = $serverGroup[0].Name
        JobName = $serverGroup[0].JobName
    } 

    # Cycle the days and populate the status columns
    for($daysIndex = 1; $daysIndex -le $days;$daysIndex++){
        $props.$daysIndex = $serverGroup | Where-Object{((Get-Date).Date - ($_.Endtime).Date) -eq $daysIndex} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Status
    }

    # Output the new object to the pipe. 
    New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property $props
} | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Temp\VeeamBackupReport.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Since I don't have access to `Get-VBRBackupSession` I need you to debug so we know where are on the right track.

Comment: Hi Matt. Thank you. I have run the script, it works so far, displays the following output:

Server1 has 30 Jobs. Lets organise them in columns now
Server2 has 30 Jobs. Lets organise them in columns now

etc etc. All underneath one another. Do you need any other info?

Comment: Not yet. This is good. Now I just need to organize by date which should be easy. Should be able to finish this morning.

Comment: What is the value you expect to be in the column? Just a true/false?

Comment: Hi Matt, Yes, just a Success/Failure, which is the equivalent of $realsessions.Status

Comment: @scryptor1 have a look at this. the output will most likely be out of colunm order but I need you to verify the logic is producing correct output. I can make it look pretty after.

Comment: It is producing a Job name column, ServerName column and then 31 columns after that :) which is great. My only concern is, I see you have Jobname and Servername being pulled from ServerGroup. How does this work?  as job name and server name reside in $realsessions?

Comment: @scryptor1 I'm not sure I understand the question. This is where my understanding of the cmdlet might be an issue. Earlier in the script I created whole new object with the `$realsession` data. Each one of those object would have had a jobname servername and the endtime of one particular job. Those later get grouped together.

Comment: thanks that makes better sense now, Ok so my output is currently one column with JobName, 1 with Servername and 31 other columns. How do we proceed?

Comment: @scryptor1 Do the columns contain the correct data that matches up with you expectations? Or are you just getting columns with no data? I would have expected you have data. Is that not the case

Comment: The only column that has data is the Job name column :) I will take a look and see if I cant spot the error and sort it out, as far as the logic of the table goes, I think you have hit the nail on the head, and I would like to consider this to be the answer :) not really sure how to add rep?

Comment: Experiment with the logic and break it down into its parts. There could be an easy error here that I made. Once you have enough rep you can up vote or if you feel this has satisfied your question you can mark this as the answer with the green check mark.

Comment: I will do and let you know how I come along. This has been a great learning experience though and I would like to thank you for your patience and for all your help. I really do appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you are trying to accomplish but something I would consider using logic that would backup your information based on what month it is. If the month is new then we use a different file. This would loosely keep with the 31 days requirement. You mentioned that you were OK with CSV output but I was already too far into this so lets keep with HTML output. I dont have access to `Get-VBRBackupSession` but you should have have a tough time incorporating this code with your cmdlets.

```powershell
function ConvertFrom-HTMLTable{
    param(
        [string]$Path
    )
    $regex = "(?s)<TABLE>.*?</TABLE>"
    $fileContent = Get-Content $Path -Raw 
    $table = (Select-String -InputObject $fileContent -Pattern $regex).Matches.Value -split "`r`n"
    $properties = ($table | Where-Object{$_ -match '^\<tr\>\<th\>'}) -split '</?th>|</?tr>' | Where-Object{$_}

    $table | Where-Object{$_ -match '^\<tr\>\<td\>'} | ForEach-Object{
        $values = $_ -split '</?td>|</?tr>' | Where-Object{$_}
        $props = @{}
        for($propIndex = 0; $propIndex -lt $properties.Count; $propIndex++){
            $props."$($properties[$propIndex])" = $values[$propIndex]
        }

        [pscustomobject]$props
    }
}


$body = "<H2>Veeam Backup Report</H2>"
$head = @"
<style>"
    {font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt;}
    TABLE{border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;}
    TH{border: 1px solid black; background: #dddddd; padding: 5px; }
    TD{border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px; }
</style>
"@

$date = get-date -Format "MMMyyyy"
$outputFile = "C:\Temp\VeeamBackupReport$date.html"
$outputData = @()
If(Test-Path $outputFile){
     $outputData = ConvertFrom-HTMLTable $outputFile
}

$result = Get-ChildItem c:\temp -File | Select-Object Name,Length,LastWriteTime,@{Label="Fluff";Expression={get-date -format "mm"}}
$outputData + $result | Select-Object Name,Length,LastWriteTime,Fluff | 
    ConvertTo-Html -Head $format -Body $body | 
    Set-Content $outputFile
```

We see if there is already a file for this month/year combination. If there is we run `ConvertFrom-HTMLTable` against it to get a custom object that contains the same properties that we are going to be exporting. Once we get the new results we combine the outputs and return them to file.

I used `Get-ChildItem` output for testing and show that it is possible to add custom fields to the output. Again, you should be able to adapt this with your own code. You should be able to run this code with no changes and wait a minute or two and run it again to see what is happening.

Comment: Hi Matt, thank you for sticking around to help me. I realise I may have been a bit unclear in explaining what exactly I needed. I will try your code out and see if I am able to produce the results I need. If I may, I would like to just attempt to clarify for you what I am trying to do: The powershell script I posted above, basically pulls the last veeam backup results and creates 3 columns, 1 showing the backup job name, 1 showing the name if the server that got backed up and 1 showing the result. But this is only for 1 day. How would I get powershell to show me a report for all 31 days?

Comment: Wait... you just mean you need to change this? `$_.EndTime -ge (Get-Date).addhours(-24)` which is what I think drives your cmdlet. What about `$_.EndTime -ge (Get-Date).adddays(-31)`

Comment: Hi Matt, I wish it was that easy hehe. I need the report to show columns for each of the 31 days for each server. But i need it to be all in one report/one file.  So basically 1 column for server names and then 31 columns for Success/Failure.

Comment: Oh.... ok. Well you still need to start with that logic then... after which you break out the resulting days into their columns... I think I can code something like this. Again, dont have that cmdlet but should be able to figure it out from your code.

Comment: @scryptor1 Does that return all the data though? just need to group and display? I think we can do this if that is correct.

Comment: I would appreciate the help. If you do need any extra info let me know. I can post screenshots of what is available. It is the veeam powershell cmdlet. Thanks Matt, I will eagerly await your feedback.

Comment: Yes it does return all the data I need. I will just change it to fetch last 31 days instead of last 24 hours. Its basically just the logic of grouping all 31 days in one table that is beating me :)

Comment: @scryptor1 do the real sessions contain the date properties still? Is it still `endtime`?

Comment: Real sessions unfortunately does not have an endtime, but sessions does show that so I am sure we can use that? The only reason I drill it down to real sessions is because real sessions is where I fetch the server names from. I have posted the outputs of $session and $realsessions for you in the main question :)

Comment: @scryptor1 That output might help me figure this out. I will _try_ and have a go at another answer.

Comment: @scryptor1 not yet. Does each `$session` have multiple `$realsessions`. So for every session is there many realsessions?

Comment: Indeed yes - $realsessions is basically what is fetching the server names and the status :)

Comment: $realsessions.status just returns the word "Success" or "Failure" which is all I need :)